# How to set listview items in horizontal position

Tags: android, json, xml, eclipse

How to set listview items in horizontal position and the list have json images which is parse from server

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ee25qr1c2oy20f1/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation for it. Also you can create custom LinearLayout with method which will have list<> argument and set it to linear layout.

Comment: the problem is my images are not hard coded images are came from server